# HighCharts Heatmap with bubbles

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have a Highcharts  Heatmap with bubbles as data-series that looks like:
[image]
Now if I have a bubble on the first/last row the Chart automatically adds a new row..
[image]

Is it possible to deactivate this behavior?

```
see: http://jsfiddle.net/10vfg03o/4/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `min` and `max` on your `y` axis:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 4,
  categories: ['< 1%', '2-10%', '11-50%', '51-90%', '91-100%'],
  title: null
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/10vfg03o/5/